# Identify a door handle type

Tags: doors, identify-a-tool

I am trying to identify the origin of a door handle (crutch on rosette, photos attached) in order to be able to replace it. The problem is that the fixing screw holes seem non-standard (at least in France, where I live), so I can't buy any handle in a local store.

Indeed, most handles in my area are apparently fixed either via 2 through screws, or via 3 screws evenly distributed. However, on mine, there are 4 screw holes, quite close to the horizontal, which means that I would not prefer to take the risk of drilling either the 2 holes for through screws or the 3 classic holes, because in any case, the new holes would be much too close to the old holes, I fear that this will weaken the wood at this spot ! And I don't really want to replace the whole door either, it's not in my budget at the moment...

Just in case, the initial problem that made me try to replace the handles is that they are in two parts : a round plate attached to the door with the screws, and the handle itself which is simply clipped to the plate... After years of use by the previous owner, the clips let me down and the handle is detached from the door, holding only by the small screw connecting it to the axis.

**My goal is to be able to find another pair of handles that could use the same screw holes.** Any indication to identify their origin, or a magic term to search for exactly that, or even a link to the same model (my dream !) would be welcome. I've searched for pages and pages and pages of handles on different sites, but the screw holes don't usually show up on merchant sites.

**the handle itself**
[image: the handle itself]

**the holes in the door**
[image: the holes in the door]

**the round plate**
[image: the round plate]

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is anything in the design, naming or marketing of door handles that would indicate the screw hole spacing of the handle mounting plate.  You may have to just buy/try various models until you find one that works.

Maybe you can drill holes in the metal mounting plates to match some of the holes you have.  The plates might take extra holes without becoming weak the way your door would.

There are handles that do not screw to the door, instead the handles screw to each other from opposite sides of the door.  Maybe a decorative plate screws to the door but that doesn't need as much strength.  The style of handle you have there doesn't work that way but maybe you could choose a different style.

Answer (score 1):

Jay [has a good idea](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/270311/34147).

Another option would be to fill the screw holes with wood<sup>*</sup> glued into place. Once the glue has dried and you've cut/sanded the ends of the filler wood flush, you can drill your new holes for a new door handle of your choosing. You might even find a new handle of similar enough design to work for you, even though it doesn't have the same 4-screw mounting system.

---

<sup>*</sup>Small dowels that will fit, splinters or splits of wood from a larger piece, even toothpicks if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can find a manufacturers' name or at least a part number on the old handle it's a needle in a haystack finding handles that mount like you have.

If the issue needs to be resolved quickly and the time to do what can be an exhaustive search is not within the scope of what you desire, then the door can be bored to fit some of the readily available locksets on the market.

Most all locksets come with templates for doing the boring on the door.  The tools are common like a drill and screwdrivers. You may have to purchase a holesaw for the correct size holes needed per the new lockset but they are not very expensive.    Then again you could hire a handyman to do the job for you.